# How to make grouped products table show in its own row above the details tab and below the images/short description?

Tags: magento2, layout, grouped-products

If it's a grouped product then how do I show the products table above the details tab in the Luma theme?

See this image to for a better explanation:
[image: Move grouped product table to details area magento2 luma theme]

Basically, I want it to work as follows:
If the product type is 'grouped' then display grouped product in its own row that is full-width.

Comment: could you Share image what you want Or code you have tried so far ?

Comment: I updated the post for a better explanation. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code before `</body>` tag in below file :

> app/code/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/Magento_GroupedProduct/layout/catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml

```
<move element="product.info" destination="content" as="grp" before="product.info.details"/>
```

It will move grouped products with add to cart. For reference see attached image:

[image]

Hope above will help!

Comment: Welcome @WillCousin, Good know it worked :)